# Customize " Select Products to Reduce" button on Reduction Order

Tags: button, order

I am trying to customize the **Select Products to Reduce** button on **Reduction** Order but I don't see the button available on Order Product and also I don't see a way to remove the button from pagelayout.

[image]

**[For More details on Reduction Order](https://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/orders-management-in-salesforce-part-2/)**

Reduction Orders

To let your users process returns or reductions on orders that have been activated, it reduction orders is enabled for your organization. 
 To reduce orders follow the below instruction

1) Once an Order is activated, You can see Reduce Order button on the Order detail page.

2) It will redirect you to New Reduction Order page, Fill the all required details and Click on Save.

3) Remove products by navigating Order products related list and click on and click on Select product to reduce, Same as above screen shot

Note:-

To reduce an order, users must have the “Create Reduction Orders”user permission.
An order must be activated before users can reduce it.
Users can’t reduce multiple orders with a single reduction order.
Users can reduce up to 200 order products in each reduction order.
Order products must have been reduced before a reduction order can be activated.
If a reduction order has been activated, users can’t delete its order products or add new ones.

Comment: Take a look at an existing order. Reduction Orders only make sense when viewed in the context of an existing order. You can only reduce items that are on the existing order.

Comment: @crmprogdev  But I want to customize it so that if there are multiple Orders and I want to reduce items from multiple orders at a time

Comment: @sf.dev can you copy and paste the full address bar of the page you have a screen shot of? This could be a visualforce button and then it wouldn't be on a layout to remove or change how that button works. It would need to be adjusted in the code for that page.

Comment: @BlairKristin Its not a visualforce page button.You could look into Reduction Order in the link (https://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/orders-management-in-salesforce-part-2/) Its a standard button but not visible under Order Products --> Buttons and Links and also not able to remove it from pagelayout

Comment: You could try using [Layout Page](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZkUEAU) from the App Exchange to get the code for the button from the Order Page Layout and the page itself as well as the code for the Reduction Order Page layout if you can locate it. You could then create your own custom page layouts for both the Order and Reduction Order Pages.

Answer (score 0):

The **Select Products to Reduce** button is not visible by default. You can make it visible by:

- going to the reduction order page layout settings
- navigate to the Order Products related list section and click on edit Properties
- go to Buttons section, you will notice that there are three "Add Products" buttons. Check all of them. See attached picture.

[image]